# Zend Studio 10 crashes with Android SDK and ADT

Tags: java, android, ubuntu, zend-studio

I downloaded new Zend Studio 10 trial version and under it's welcome page I included Android Developer Tools. After it has made update, I tried to create a sample android project upon which I received an error that Android SDK is missing. I went to Android developer website and downloaded latest Android SDK (for linux (Im running Ubuntu 12)). Then I told Zend studio where my folder was, on which I received an error that my ADT is outdated. I entered repository (https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/) in Install new software and performed an Android ADT update to version 22. After that I could proceed to link my SDK to Zendstudio 10. All was marvelous and I got access to Android manager (if i'm correct) where I could download different API versions etc. I performed update to Tools as well.. After update I made a Zend Studio restart (I still couldnt make sample project). Upon loading of IDE, it crashes in like 5 seconds. So, I looked at errorlog (Zend's) and only hint that i got was:

**A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:**

SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0xaeba3e08, pid=32629, tid=2867575616

JRE version: 6.0_27-b27
Java VM: OpenJDK Client VM (20.0-b12 mixed mode, sharing linux-x86 )
Derivative: IcedTea6 1.12.5
Distribution: Ubuntu 12.10, package 6b27-1.12.5-0ubuntu0.12.10.1
Problematic frame:
 C  [libsqlite3.so.0+0x67e08]  sqlite3_step+0x3e8

Interesting enough is that my boss told me that he got it all working out of the box (as if Zend 10 installed sdk initially). Could I be missing something?

Comment: Close voters: this question seems highly on-topic to me.